# Mcrypt and encript in php 7.2

Tags: php

```
final class Encryption {
    private $key;

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = hash('sha256', $key, true);
    }

    public function encrypt($value) {
        return strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, hash('sha256', $this->key, true), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)), '+/=', '-_,');
    }

    public function decrypt($value) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, hash('sha256', $this->key, true), base64_decode(strtr($value, '-_,', '+/=')), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
}
```

The above code does not work anymore in php 7.2 because of the mcrypt function. How can I convert it to some equivalent function in php 7.2?

Comment: You can't. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is a bastard format peculiar to MCrypt. You'll need to use an older version of PHP to re-encrypt everything to something compatible with PHP 7.

Comment: There is no equivalent. Mcrypt hasn't been touched in 11 or 12 years. No updates, no nothing. I call it the slap to your face wake up call. Unless you did manual padding (not seeing it) its impossible to decrypt with openSSL. Downgrade PHP, decrypt and re-encrypt with up to date standards.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's mcrypt library was deprecated in favor of openssl.

I recommend using AES-CBC-256 along with `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` to replace MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Comment: You have to do this. Is it just replacing functions of the code that works?